# What does "I can prove it on an abacus" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I've got a feeling it means "I can prove it in a very simple and an ostensive way".
Is this so?

Update:
The context.
http://www.laddertheory.com/commoncriticisms.htm
Search for "abacus".

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could do with context, but when I have heard that, it is intended almost as an insult.

"So simple, it can be proved using the simplest of things."

The use implies one of two things usually, either a) the person who is questioning the validity should know it to be true, as it is too simple to bother proving, or b) the person stating the line is very arrogant and is showing off.

Comment: I've reread the source. Looks like I've got case "b". Thanks for thorough explanation.

Comment: @Nek: I dunno — it looks more like case (a) to me, that he’s saying: “look, this is bloody obviously true.”  The site as a whole certainly has lots of arrogance and showing off, but this isn’t I think an example of it.

Comment: @PLL: The two do overlap, what is "bloody obviously true" to a very arrogant person within their own field, is a much wider gamut than the general populous. ;-)

Comment: @Orbling: populACE, populACE, populACE. (Sorry, pet peeve.)

Comment: @Martha: Oh yes, noun vs. adjective, always screw that one up - too much of a certain game by Bullfrog as a child.

Comment: I agree this is an overlapping.

Answer (score 5):

Absent further information, "I can prove it on an abacus" simply means something is arithmetically demonstrable.

But it is certainly not an idiom I've ever heard to describe simplicity. "I can draw you a diagram" and "You can point to it" and "It ain't rocket science" (or the funnier "It ain't rocket surgery") are idioms that do express something that is uncomplicated and easy.

Comment: Have you never heard it used as an insult?  I certainly have a few times, mainly by arrogant mathematicians mind.

Comment: @Orbling: It takes more than that to insult me. Thankfully, I remain oblivious to most of the higher-level slurs mathematicians throw at me. Ignorance is bliss.

Comment: @Robusto: I did not mean directly at you. ;-)

Comment: @Orbling: I know. I am just puffing myself up like a blowfish so that dangerous mathematicians keep their distance.

Comment: @Robusto: Mathematicians tend only to be dangerous when they are allowed near physics. ;-)

Comment: @Orbling: *Touché*. I consider nuclear fission (and its brighter cousin, fusion) to be the most dangerous type of insult imaginable.

Comment: @Robusto: Aye, as insults go, the invention of the A-bomb was certainly two-fingers up to humanity.

Answer (score 1):

I think it means something that I know in any single details or assyom. So, I don't need a computer to elaborate the results, I'm so familiar with the concept that, one step at a time, I can prove it with an abacus.